# How to list the untracked files in darcs?

Tags: version-control, status, ls, darcs

For example, in Git, when I run `git status`, I see whether there are any untracked files in my working dir.

How do I check whether there are untracked files with darcs?

(I'm using darcs-2.1.2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`darcs whatsnew` (which can be abbreviated to just `darcs wh` or `darcs wha`) is equivalent to `git diff` (keep in mind, though, that darcs has no concept of Git index).

`darcs whatsnew -ls`(same as `--look-for-adds --summary`) is closer to `git status`, giving an overview of changes in the working directory:

```
helm:myproj oleg$ darcs wha -ls
M ./basicmodule.py -2 +1
A ./newfile.py
a ./temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

(Found the answer at http://irclog.perlgeek.de/darcs/2009-04-01.)

```
darcs whatsnew -l
```

According to `darcs whatsnew --help`:

```
-l  --look-for-adds       look for (non-boring) files that could be added
```

Bare `darcs whatsnew` prints a huge output with the diffs (if there are a lot of diffs), so that even if the info was there, I couldn't see it, but this option is nice.

For example:

```
/etc/modprobe.d # darcs init
/etc/modprobe.d # darcs add -r .
/etc/modprobe.d # darcs whatsnew -l
A ./aliases
A ./alsa-modindex
A ./alsa-modindex.rpmnew
A ./arch
A ./blacklist
A ./blacklist-cups
A ./blacklist-edac
A ./blacklist-framebuffer
A ./blacklist-hwmon
A ./blacklist-net
A ./blacklist-watchdog
A ./install
A ./isapnp
A ./options
A ./oss
/etc/modprobe.d # darcs remove ./alsa-modindex.rpmnew
/etc/modprobe.d # darcs whatsnew -l
A ./aliases
A ./alsa-modindex
A ./arch
A ./blacklist
A ./blacklist-cups
A ./blacklist-edac
A ./blacklist-framebuffer
A ./blacklist-hwmon
A ./blacklist-net
A ./blacklist-watchdog
A ./install
A ./isapnp
A ./options
A ./oss
a ./alsa-modindex.rpmnew
/etc/modprobe.d #
```

So, a small "a" is for untracked files. Big "A" is probably for the ones added, but not recorded, is it?

Yes, it is. After I ran `darcs record`, only the untracked one remains:

```
/etc/modprobe.d # darcs whatsnew -l
a ./alsa-modindex.rpmnew
/etc/modprobe.d #
```